# Use Laravel touches without global scopes

Tags: php, laravel, global-scope

**Concept Problem:**
I have a very simple problem when using the `touches` attribute, to automatically update timestamp on a depending model; it correctly does so but also applies the global scopes.

Is there any way to turn this functionality off? Or to ask specifically for **automatic** `touches` to ignore global scopes?

---

**Concrete Example**:
When an ingredient model is updated all related recipes should be touched. This works fine, except we have a `globalScope` for separating the recipes based on locales, that also gets used when applying the touches.

---

Ingredient Model:

```
class Ingredient extends Model
{
    protected $touches = ['recipes'];

    public function recipes() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Recipe::class);
    }

}
```

Recipe Model:

```
class Recipe extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::addGlobalScope(new LocaleScope);
    }

    public function ingredients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Ingredient::class);
    }
}
```

Locale Scope:

```
class LocaleScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $locale = app(Locale::class);

        return $builder->where('locale', '=', $locale->getLocale());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to explicitly avoid a global scope for a given query, you may use the `withoutGlobalScope()` method. The method accepts the class name of the global scope as its only argument.

```
$ingredient->withoutGlobalScope(LocaleScope::class)->touch();
$ingredient->withoutGlobalScopes()->touch();
```

Since you're not calling `touch()` directly, in your case it will require a bit more to make it work.

You specify relationships that should be touched in model `$touches` attribute. Relationships return query builder objects. See where I'm going?

```
protected $touches = ['recipes'];

public function recipes() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Recipe::class)->withoutGlobalScopes();
}
```

If that messes with the rest of your application, just create a new relationship specifically for touching (heh :)

```
protected $touches = ['recipesToTouch'];

public function recipes() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Recipe::class);
}

public function recipesToTouch() {
   return $this->recipes()->withoutGlobalScopes();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can define a relationship in the model and pass parameters to it like following:

```
public function recipes($isWithScope=true)
{
    if($isWithScope)
        return $this->belongsToMany(Recipe::class);
    else
        return $this->recipes()->withoutGlobalScopes();
}
```

then use it like this `recipes->get();` and `recipes(false)->get();`

Comment: And how do you pass a parameter through the `touches` attribute? Without this key information, this is not a solution.